# In MVC, how do I create a view that will update a parent model, and all children models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, parent

I'm brand new to MVC, still trying to read and learn the ropes, and this question has come up.

If I had a model, let's say User, that looks like this:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual Child Child { get; set; }
}
```

And a model, Child, which is a child entity to the parent User:

```
public partial class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Toy Toy { get; set; }
}
```

And a final model, Toy, which is a child model to the parent model Child:

```
public partial class Toy
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ToyName { get; set; }
}
```

And I wanted to create a View that would have fields available for all of them, how would I write the controller/view so that if all the fields were filled it would create the records correctly? So that the ToyName would be for the appropriate Toy, which would be for the appropriate Child, which would be for the appropriate User?

This is just an example I was thinking of, because I wanted to try to make a sort of pet project to practice MVC, and I can't seem to find many sources explaining how to do this.

Comment: @JayMason - Please learn the difference between is-a and has-a relationships.  A child is not a toy, a child has-a toy.

Comment: This question is too broad, and requires far more detail than a single post can supply.  What have you tried?  What are you having trouble with?  Ask a specific question and not a general how do I..

Comment: This question is too broad because you are asking us for guidance in the design of classes with parent/child relationships and their use, from top to bottom, in MVC. Answering requires a lengthy post with design decisions being made or assumed. Is your problem between the view and controller? Saving to the database? How to better design class relationships around Child/User/Toy? Something else? Please ask a specific question.

Answer (score 1):

It's really straight forward.

A minimalist example.

The View EditUser.cshtml:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.User

@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveUser", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Username)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Username) <br />

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Child.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Child.Name) <br/>

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Child.Toy.ToyName)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Child.Toy.ToyName) <br />

    <input type="submit" />

}
```

The action methods in the Home controller:

```
public ActionResult EditUser(User user)
{
    return View(user);
}

public ActionResult SaveUser(User user)
{
    // Do something with user to save it

    // then show the Edit form again

    return View("EditUser", user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you will have to scaffolding your user ViewModel. This will allow you to fetch User -> Child -> Toy data.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2013/09/20/managing-entity-relationships-with-mvc-scaffolding/

Answer (score 0):

You will probably had to use Viewmodels to fetch all the data from all those different tables. Check on them.